# Why does d3 say some nodes are missing after applying link force?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to follow along with a book called Interactive data visualization for the web. I would like to try to build the force graph described there. Everything is fine when I use this books dummy data, but when I try my own data, I keep getting an error saying node 17 is missing. When I change this node's target to 16, it will say 18 is missing. Eventually, when I change 16, 17 and 18 all to 15, the graph will finally display. But some nodes' edges are still missing in the displayed graph.

I tried all different string/integer possibilities for the data without success. The data is put together with a forEach from a database query result. The source and target integers are the node's ids in the database. The last result will because of that have an unnecessary comma, but that doesn't seem to matter either.

When I keep the nodes original target values and delete this line of code: `.force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links))` the graph will display without edges, the nodes will scatter all over the SVG. When I sort the data by the source data, the console will say d3 is not defined... I'm really lost on this one.

I've watched many posts in which undefined values or null values are giving as a cause, but I don't really understand how to change my code accordingly. In the console, it's clearly visible that some nodes have an index number assigned to them after applying force, and some don't. But I just have no ideas on where to go. Please help me the right direction. This is how I tried to put together the graph's data in Node.js:

```
var graph = {
            nodes: [
                <% nodes.forEach(function(a){ %>
                    {category: "<%= a.properties.Name %>"},
                <% }); %>
            ],
            links: [
                <% edges.forEach(function(a){ %>
                    {"source": <%= a.source %>, "target": <%= a.target %>},
                <% }); %>
            ]
        }
```

This is what's inside the dataset called graph:

```
var graph = {
            nodes: [
           {Name: "b"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "b"},
           {Name: "b"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "b"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "c"},
           {Name: "d"},
           {Name: "d"},
           {Name: "a"},
           {Name: "c"}
        ],
        links: [
            {source: 8, target: 3},
            {source: 3, target: 5},
            {source: 3, target: 6},
            {source: 3, target: 7},
            {source: 3, target: 11},
            {source: 3, target: 12},
            {source: 8, target: 0},
            {source: 0, target: 13},
            {source: 0, target: 14},
            {source: 8, target: 9},
            {source: 9, target: 17},
            {source: 9, target: 18},
            {source: 14,target: 15},
            {source: 14,target: 16},
            {source: 8, target: 10}                  
            ]
        }
```

This is the d3 code I copied from the book:

```
var w = 800;
        var h = 400;

        var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)

        var force = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.edges))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(w/1).y(h/1))

        var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
            .data(graph.edges)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .style("stroke", "#ccc")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)


        var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)


            nodes.append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name
            })

            force.on("tick", function() {
            edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
            nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
            })
```

This is the error. Please help me show why this is happening [image: error]

ps. This is the dummy data from the book. I really don't get why this works and mine doesn't.

```
var graph = {
        nodes: [
        { name: "Adam" },
        { name: "Bob" },
        { name: "Carrie" },
        { name: "Donovan" },
        { name: "Edward" },
        { name: "Felicity" },
        { name: "George" },
        { name: "Hannah" },
        { name: "Iris" },
        { name: "Jerry" }
        ],
        edges: [
        { source: 0, target: 1 },
        { source: 0, target: 2 },
        { source: 0, target: 3 },
        { source: 0, target: 4 },
        { source: 1, target: 5 },
        { source: 2, target: 5 },
        { source: 2, target: 5 },
        { source: 3, target: 4 },
        { source: 5, target: 8 },
        { source: 5, target: 9 },
        { source: 6, target: 7 },
        { source: 7, target: 8 },
        { source: 8, target: 9 }
        ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is very simple. You have only 16 nodes:

```js
var graph = {
  nodes: [{
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "d"
  }, {
    Name: "d"
  }, {
    Name: "a"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }],
  links: [{
    source: 8,
    target: 3
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 5
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 6
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 7
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 11
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 12
  }, {
    source: 8,
    target: 0
  }, {
    source: 0,
    target: 13
  }, {
    source: 0,
    target: 14
  }, {
    source: 8,
    target: 9
  }, {
    source: 9,
    target: 17
  }, {
    source: 9,
    target: 18
  }, {
    source: 14,
    target: 15
  }, {
    source: 14,
    target: 16
  }, {
    source: 8,
    target: 10
  }]
}

console.log("number of nodes: " + graph.nodes.length)
```

Their indices go from `0` to `15` (zero based).

However, in your `links` array, you have source/targets higher than that, like 17 or 18! That won't work. Notice that the original data has only 10 nodes, and the edges' array has `9` as the maximum index for the source or target.

Here is your code and your data, changing everything higher than 15 to other number:

```js
var graph = {
  nodes: [{
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "b"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }, {
    Name: "d"
  }, {
    Name: "d"
  }, {
    Name: "a"
  }, {
    Name: "c"
  }],
  links: [{
    source: 8,
    target: 3
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 5
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 6
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 7
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 11
  }, {
    source: 3,
    target: 12
  }, {
    source: 8,
    target: 0
  }, {
    source: 0,
    target: 13
  }, {
    source: 0,
    target: 14
  }, {
    source: 8,
    target: 9
  }, {
    source: 9,
    target: 10
  }, {
    source: 9,
    target: 10
  }, {
    source: 14,
    target: 15
  }, {
    source: 14,
    target: 10
  }, {
    source: 8,
    target: 10
  }]
}

var w = 800;
var h = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)

var force = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(w / 2).y(h / 2))

var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1)

var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)

nodes.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  })

force.on("tick", function() {
  edges.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
  nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your reply! The source and target numbers are as high as 17 and 18 because the nodes have 17 or 18 as their id in the database. It wasn't very smart to think this had to be right because it's this way in the database. I deleted and added some nodes, so the id number ended up higher then the number of nodes. I guess I have to find a way to rearrange the source and target numbers using javascript, right? Thank you